# Logic of Regex to split string in Javascript to multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

It's hard to put everything in the question's title since it's specific depends on what string people want to split. But here it is:

I have a string in which there are multiple script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/something-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/something-2.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/something-3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/something-1.css">
```

I want to split this string into multiple string, each contains a script tag (ignore link tags). This is how I did it:

```
var scripts = code.match(/<script.*src=.*(\/>|<\/script>)/g);
```

This is to match script tags with closing tag either `/>` or `</script>`. However, with this current regex, I always get:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/something-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/something-2.js"/>
```

as a string - not two.

How do I regex something like:

```
/<script.*src=( (not script not link) /> | (not link) <\/script> )/g
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `.*` to `.*?` to match as little as possible rather than as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle this is to use "src" as the attribute of the "script" tag by using the xmldom and take the page in as a partial or full xml doc. It's a positive way to grab them and avoid the links.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, what you're trying to do is not possible.  But if you can make certain simplifying assumptions about the source string, you can create a regex that's good enough.  Here's what I would try:

```
/<script(?:\s+\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*")+\s*/?>(?:</script>)?/gi
```

explanation:

- `<script` matches the beginning of the start tag.
- `(?:\s+\w+\s*=\s*"[^"]*")+` consumes one or more attributes
- `\s*/?>` matches the end of the start tag.  If it's a self-closing tag, the `/?` consumes the slash.
- `\s*(?:</script>)?` otherwise, this matches the end tag.

The basic idea is to replace the `.*` with something that can't match the `>` at the end of the start tag and thus "escape" to match more than you want.  Of course, there are no guarantees.  I don't even know if your HTML is valid, and there are many ways this regex can be fooled even in valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like

```
var rx = /<script.+?src=.+?\/(script)?>/gim;
```

This will match anything:

- starting with `<script`
- having at least 1 more character (can be a space, for example, or some other attribute-value pairs)
- having `src=`
- having least 1 more character
- then either `/>` or `/script>`

and the flags…

- the **i** flag is for case insensitivity
- the **g** flag is for multiple matches
- the **m** flag is for multiline sources (assuming these lines will actually be lines themselves and not a single line in total)

**EDIT:** I hadn't taken into account the possibility of having a get value like `&src=etc` in the address in the value of **src** attribute.

Comment: The `m` flag is irrelevant.  It only matters if you're using anchors (`^` and `$`) to match the beginning and end of lines.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance (this is a serious question) but what if the closing tag is in the following line, for example? Would omitting the **m** flag still let it be catched?

Comment: In that case, your regex would fail because `.` doesn't match newlines, and multiline mode doesn't change that.  All it does is change the behavior of `^` and `$`, allowing them to match at line boundaries as well as at the beginning and end of the whole string.  The oft-repeated advice "if the source string is multiline, you must use multiline mode" is wrong.  You may be thinking of *single-line* or *DOTALL* mode, which enables `.` to match any character, but JavaScript doesn't support that.